# Can I get access to NFC without manifest permission in android?

Tags: android, nfc, android-permissions

I need to create app with optional NFC functionality. 
Can I get access to NFC without manifest permission (Android)? Or should I create two apps: an NFC version and one without it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated as per finding of [thorbear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503668/thorbear)

The `uses-feature` element so that your application shows up in Google Play only for devices that have NFC hardware:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

If your application uses NFC functionality, *but that functionality is not crucial to your application, you can omit the uses-feature element* and check for NFC avalailbility at runtime by checking to see if [getDefaultAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#getDefaultAdapter(android.content.Context)) is null.

---

> This is not possible without adding permission into manifest. And you
>   do not required to create two apps for such case.

Read [Requesting NFC Access in the Android Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#manifest) for more details

<s>But yes you have a way to say "*My application uses NFC feature but optional*".
For this you need to add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />` into manifest. So Google play can make your application available for all devices which have `NFC` or not have.</s>

**Note :** If you do not add this `<uses-feature .../>` tag into manifest with `android:required="false"`, Google Play will treat your application as "*this application is only for devices which having NFC*". And a device which does not have `NFC` feature, can not download your application from Google Play.

---

Here is manifest example

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

</manifest>
```

Read more about [`<uses-feature>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Comment: Do you have any references for the note about `<uses-feature>` needing to be declared explicitly as `required="false"`? According to the [linked documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) for `<uses-feature>` NFC is not on the list of `Permissions that Imply Feature Requirements`.

Comment: @Thorbear Yes. Please read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#manifest

Comment: Your reference seems to imply the opposite:
`If your application uses NFC functionality, but that functionality is not crucial to your application, you can omit the uses-feature element [...]`

Comment: Done. PLease look now

Answer (score 2):

You can't get access to NFC without adding the following permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```